# bootstrap .modal has lower z-index than youtube iframe on top fade in (only in firefox)

Tags: iframe, youtube, z-index

when the bootstrap fades in from the top it shows up underneath the youtube iframe embedded videos. once the fade is done it shows up on top like it should. i have set wmodes to transparent, opaque set the z index on both the fade and modal high and still with no luck. strangely this is only happening in **firefox**. ie chrome even the finicky ipad all work! how can i fix this?!?

[image]

```
<div class="modal fade" id="test"> 
    <div class="modal-header"> <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a> <h3>You have already voted!</h3> </div> 
    <div class="modal-body"> <p>You may vote again tomorrow.</p> </div> 

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

after messing around with the bootstrap's css having an opacity of 1.0 on the .modal.fade solved the problem:

```
    .modal.fade {
 opacity: 1.0;
  top: -25%;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, top 0.3s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, top 0.3s ease-out;
       -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear, top 0.3s ease-out;
          transition: opacity 0.3s linear, top 0.3s ease-out;

}
```

not sure how this only affected only firefox if someone could explain that would be nice.